# Websraping Behind Pay Wall, multiple pages

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to web scrape a table from a dataset table on a real estate data website. I have previously run a similar idea on on a property listing website in my region (United Arab Emirates) https://propertyfinder.ae Where I would run a script similar to this. However, this data site requires you to get past a pay wall to have access. I do have access but I want to scrape the listings on the site and click past several thousands of pages. I know how to scrape past a single page when I have the html saved locally.

So far my code looks like:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

#Login
EMAIL = "EMAIL"
PASSWORD = "PASSWORD"
BASIC_AUTH = HTTPBasicAuth(EMAIL, PASSWORD)
LOGIN_URL = "https://app.datafinder.ae/login"
TABLE_URL = "https://app.datafinder.ae/prices-and-transactions/record-data?d=2020-12&df=2020-03&dt=2021-03&e=1&l=1&ot=1"
response = requests.get(LOGIN_URL,headers={},auth=BASIC_AUTH)

#I want to change html to the response from the table url
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
header = [th.text for th in soup.table.find_all('th')]
data = []

#Forming Table
for tr in soup.table.find_all('tr'):
    data.append([td.text for td in tr.find_all('td')])
    
#Saving Table
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=header)
```

A sample of the html file for the page of the listings is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xZuNA_I8GHprJdZ8b_TuwE7DG3R8Xmoa/view?usp=sharing) How can I convert the response variable so that bs4 can accept it right now it gives me:

```
TypeError: object of type 'Response' has no len()
```

Also, since the table does not load a new page url when clicking next, how would I be able to access all the pages through. The button html is below (same as the html file):

```
<div class="_3rAkcwFt _10rWi6uP" data-key="paginator-item-next-page">
    <div class="_3yzH6IgI _1p6NuvAE">
        <span class="_34-GPJZM">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 128 128">
                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="...">
                </path>
            </svg>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

How would I go about automating flipping through all the pages?

Comment: Try: `soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')` and remove the `with open(....` part

Comment: Your question is missing a lot of details. please [edit] your question and sort it out in order for us to understand it. `1`. you are using `Basic AUTH` which is not useful here. `2.` you are trying to login using the wrong url. `3.` you even not using the same session to maintain the login process. `4.` `response` variable is holding just the response status code! am voting down to close that question since it's a dump question which is not targeting specific issue.

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη I understand your frustration, ignoring all the login and `Basic AUTH` issues (I used a diff url to test the login method), would you be able to point out how to change pages?

Comment: @MartinEvans It gives an error when I try it `[Errno 36] File name too long: b'<!DOCTYPE html>...`

Answer (score 1):

Below is the correct way to handle your case.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        data = {
            "data": {
                "attributes": {
                    "email": "Email",  # Insert Your Email
                    "password": "pass"  # Insert Your Password
                },
                "type": "user_login"
            }
        }
        req.post(url, data=data)
        params = {
            "d": "2020-12",
            "df": "2020-03",
            "dt": "2021-03",
            "e": "1",
            "l": "1",
            "ot": "1"
        }
        r = req.get(
            'https://app.datafinder.ae/prices-and-transactions/record-data', params=params)
        df = pd.read_html(r.content)
        print(df)


main('https://app.datafinder.ae/api/v1/user/login')
```

Here, we maintained the same session, and reading the HTML table into dataframe.

But regarding the following point:

> Also, since the table does not load a new page url when clicking next, how would I be able to access all the pages through. The button html is below (same as the html file):

i will translate it into (The page url is not changed once you click `Next`)

That's mean you are dealing with `JavaScript` content which is loaded dynamically once the page loads.

That's taking us to another point where you need to figure out from where the data is Rendered or you've to use `selenium` or any other library which can render the HTML since `requests` can't render HTML for you.